# suggestion for correct python syntax

Tags: python, django, syntax, workflow, web2py

I am trying to design a configuration pattern which contain a combination of classes.
Let say we have a class.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

Now i want to design a configuration pattern which i want to be defined something like this or a variant of this.

```
Workflow = Node(1,2) & ( Node(4,2) | Node(5,6) ) & Node(1,7)
```

I actually want to save it in a file and then pick this up later and then break all nodes and use them in the same order as defined here.
But this is syntax wise incorrect.
Can you please suggest me some alternative for this ?
Can i use this same pattern as defined above?

I don't want to use dictionaries and list to save them because they only provide ',' as a separator. And also dictionaries are not ordered and i will loose the order in which i defined the configuration or nodes.

Comment: `collections.OrderedDict` preserves the order. You can use modules like [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) to store actual python objects in files(in bytes form) and later load them in memory.

Comment: Thanks for replying @AshwiniChaudhary
I know about OrderedDict but i really want to avoid dictionaries.
My main aim is the design or the configuration pattern.
I want to know can if can use the design defined above and if not, what's the best way to do it.
My main focus is on the separators there '&' and '|'.
since configurations are going to be a routes for the workflow, where '&' define a required node and '|' a optional.

Comment: @HardikJuneja I like your approach of trying to craft a DSL for this, but you may want to think again before using '&' and '|' to represent required and optional. When overloading operators you should always try and make sure the behavior is intuitive. The meaning of these two operators is ingrained in programmers as meaning 'and' and 'or', and could confuse people if they are re-purposed to mean 'required' and 'optional'.

Comment: @robjohncox +1 for the intuitiveness.  In my example I assumed he means "and"/"or", but using that approach, he can name the operators whatever comes most readable.

Comment: @robjohncox that was just an example, I will try not to overload operate that can confuse the other developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to support that syntax for building a `Workflow` from `Node`s, then you  should be able to do this using operator overloading. Here is an excellent [quick reference on operators that can be overloaded](http://rgruet.free.fr/PQR26/PQR2.6.html#SpecialMethods) in Python.

As suggested by @AshwiniChaudhary the `pickle` module could handle storing Python objects in files.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure from your question, but If the point is to store an arbitrary configuration tree I'd advice you to stick with "normal" data types if possible.  That way your configuration data will be far more easy to store and far more portable.

Regarding the semantics and order, you can always do something like this (a little bit Lisp-like thing):

```
conf = [
    ['Workflow',
        ['and',
            ['Node', 1, 2],
            ['or',
                ['Node', 4, 2],
                ['Node', 5, 6]
            ],
            ['Node', 1, 7]
        ]
    ]
]
```

If it's too ugly for your humans, you can use [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/) (not in core Python libs though; use [PyYaml](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation)):

```
- - Workflow
  - - and
    - [Node, 1, 2]
    - - or
      - [Node, 4, 2]
      - [Node, 5, 6]
    - [Node, 1, 7]
```

(Note that I'm using lowercase for operators and first-uppercase for classes.)